# Error with Chado module installation

Tags: database, debugging, 10

As part of college course work, I am required to make a genomic database with a local website with basic features. I have installed Drupal 10.2.3 with PostgreSQL 14.11, PHP 8.3.4 and Tripal 4.0.0-alpha2.

I am facing error during Chado module installation via Home > Administration > Tripal > Data Storage > Chado > Install Chado. I have already enabled it from the 'Extend' tab. I am new to Drupal as well as website development in general. From my limited understanding, it has something to do with missing "drupal_chado_installations" table but it seems to exist when I give command

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'drupal_chado_installations'
```

[image]

Below is the Chado installation error when I try installing through my local server's website @http://localhost/admin/tripal/storage/chado/install

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.
>
> ```
> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "drupal_chado_installations" does not exist
> ```
>
> LINE 3: "drupal_chado_installations" "i" ^: SELECT
> "i"."install_id" AS "install_id", "i"."schema_name" AS "schema_name",
> "i"."version" AS "version", "i"."created" AS "created", "i"."updated"
> AS "updated" FROM "drupal_chado_installations" "i"; Array ( ) in
> Drupal\tripal_chado\Database\ChadoConnection->getAvailableInstances()
> (line 279 of
> modules/contrib/tripal/tripal_chado/src/Database/ChadoConnection.php).
>
> ```
> Drupal\Core\Database\StatementWrapperIterator->execute() (Line: 851) Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->query() (Line: 239)
> ```
>
> Drupal\pgsql\Driver\Database\pgsql\Connection->query() (Line: 525)
> Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Select->execute() (Line: 155)
> Drupal\pgsql\Driver\Database\pgsql\Select->execute() (Line: 279)
> Drupal\tripal_chado\Database\ChadoConnection->getAvailableInstances()
> (Line: 47) Drupal\tripal_chado\Form\ChadoInstallForm->buildForm()
> call_user_func_array() (Line: 536)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm() (Line: 283)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (Line: 73)
> Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult()
> call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> (Line: 627) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()
> (Line: 121)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext()
> (Line: 97)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> (Line: 181) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
> (Line: 76) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line:
> 58) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 28)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 32)
> Drupal\big_pipe\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 50)
> Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line:
> 51) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line:
> 36) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle() (Line: 51)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 704)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

My settings.php file already contains the database connection details so online solutions mentioning that are not working

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'teak_wood_genes_db',
  'username' => 'postgres_molecular',
  'password' => '**********',
  'prefix' => 'drupal_',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '5432',
  'driver' => 'pgsql',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\pgsql\\Driver\\Database\\pgsql',
  'autoload' => 'core/modules/pgsql/src/Driver/Database/pgsql/',
);
```

Comment: Drupal Answers is a question-and-answer site. If you have followed all documentation and are experiencing bugs you should report bugs to the project maintainers. That said I noticed you are using table prefixing. Perhaps this alpha-quality module cannot handle that and it needs a bug reported.

Comment: Noted. I will try contacting the maintainers

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error is due to table prefix. Table prefix is depreciated in latest versions and threw errors. Solved by removing the entire database (after backup) and creating a new one without prefix, also removing the prefix in settings.php file.